# Why LWUIT ComboBox's blank item is not selectable?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-combobox

I created a `ComboBox` of `String[]` :

`genretxt=new ComboBox(new String[]{"Féminin","Masculin"});`

The problem is that the popup has a blank item when clicking the `ComboBox` at runtime , but this blank item is not clickable : even though I click it then the selection remains at the previous selection.

I tried to add the `""` String to the array argument of the ComboBox : `genretxt = new ComboBox(new String[]{"","Féminin","Masculin"});` but in runtime there is `two` blank items , so it is not very good to see !

Also the `genretxt` component's value is not mandatory in my application so the user can select `null` in the `ComboBox`.

I tried to derive the `ComboBox` class and implemented the `createPopupList()` method but the problem is the same !

So how to make it possible to select a null item in the `ComboBox` ?

Comment: Can you write a complete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure where you see that blank and without an exact way to reproduce, version of LWUIT & theme used there isn't much I can help with there.

In order to allow selecting a blank you need to actually add it to the combo box, there is no way around it. LWUIT has a special case for empty strings where they occupy 0 space. You can resolve it either by having a string like `[None]` or by calling `setRenderingPrototype("XXXXXXXX")` or by creating your own renderer.

Comment: The LWUIT version I use is 1.4